# How to exclude international domains from Google search results?

Tags: google-search

It seems that "-site:*.domain" does not work neither in non-ascii not in xn-- from.

Comment: I think this is off topic here, try posting it in WebApps or Super User

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

- As an example, if I enter `shoes` in google.com search box, I get shoes from everywhere but focused on New Zealand.
- If I enter `shoes nz` or `shoes site:.nz`, I get only New Zealand sites.
- If I enter `shoes -nz`, I get everything except New Zealand.
- This also works to exclude if its in the url `shoes -inurl:nz`;
- Have never tried this, but should work to search the text `shoes -intext:nz`
- Have never tried this, but should work to search the title `shoes -intitle:nz`

It relies on `nz` appearing in the domain name or the description tag.  So it's not foolproof, but its the best you are going to get.

Comment: Sorry but I was asking about non-ascii domains. Ideally about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain#Internationalized_ccTLDs. I cannot restrict those.